# Follow up to Shuffling a list of track indices

Tags: java, shuffle

This is the improved code to my last [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59294/shuffling-a-list-of-track-indices):

```
package Utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A ShuffleGenerator will create a private list of indices and shuffle them.
 * You can access the shuffled indices with the methods getPrevious() and getNext().
 * The method initialize(long, int) can be called as often as you want but should be called at least once
 * after creating an instance of the ShuffleGenerator class. 
 * <p>
 * Example for a ShuffleGenerator situation :
 * <pre>
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * //Your list
 * ArrayList<Whatever> myList = new ArrayList<Whatever>();
 * //... fill list with items
 * 
 * ShuffleGenerator generator = new ShuffleGenerator();
 * generator.initialize( 546884668, myList.size() );
 * 
 *  //Holds now a random index from myList
 *  int shuffledIndex = generator.getNext();
 * }
 * <pre>
 * @author Davlog
 * @see ShuffleGenerator#ShuffleGenerator()
 * @see ShuffleGenerator#getPrevious()
 * @see ShuffleGenerator#getNext()
 * @see ShuffleGenerator#initialize(long, int)
 * @see ShuffleGenerator#setTrack(int)
 */
public class ShuffleGenerator {

    private ArrayList<Integer> indexList;
    private int currentListIndex;

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    public ShuffleGenerator(){
        indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        currentListIndex = 0;
    }

    /**
     * This will create a shuffled list with the indices from 0 to size-1.
     * When calling again, it will re-create a new shuffle list as long as the seed is different.
     * @param seed for shuffling. Should be always different for re-initialization. 
     * @param size the amount of indices for the shuffled list.
     */
    public void initialize( long seed, int size ){

        indexList.clear();
        currentListIndex = 0;

        if( size > 0 ){

            //fill it with indices
            ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
                indices.add(i);
            }

            Random rnd = new Random(seed);

            do{

                int index = rnd.nextInt(indices.size());
                indexList.add( indices.remove(index) );

            }while( !indices.isEmpty() );           
        }       
    }

    public int getCurrent(){
        //if currentIndex is out of bounds, return -1 
        if( currentListIndex >= indexList.size() ){
            return -1;
        }

        return indexList.get(currentListIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Get the next index of the shuffled list.
     * @return -1 if failed, otherwise the index.
     */
    public int getNext(){
        //if currentIndex is out of bounds, return -1 
        if( currentListIndex+1 >= indexList.size() ){
            return -1;
        }

        return indexList.get(++currentListIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Get the previous index of the shuffled list.
     * @return -1 if failed, otherwise the index.
     */
    public int getPrevious(){
        //if currentIndex is out of bounds, return -1 
        if( currentListIndex-1 < 0 || indexList.isEmpty() ){
            return -1;
        }

        return indexList.get(--currentListIndex);
    }

    /**
     * This method will try to find the index you passed in the shuffled list
     * and set the current index of it to the position of your index. 
     * The methods getPrevious() and getNext() will then give you the index before
     * or after that index.
     * @param index The index from your list.
     * @return True if succeeded, otherwise false.
     */
    public boolean setTrack( int index ){
        /*
         * Loop through the whole list and stop when it has been found
         * Found will then be returned.
         */
        boolean found = false;
        for( int listIndex : indexList ){
            if( listIndex == index ){
                currentListIndex = listIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Also added a few methods to it suchs as `setTrack(int)`. Is it better or did I forget something? I did not want to use an `int[]` array because I want to be able to resize the list by just calling the `initialize(long,int)` method. However, if you say now that it'd better to create a new instance of a `ShuffleGenerator` than re-initialize the list, I'll change it.

Comment: If you wish to make a follow-up question you should accept one of the answers on your previous question.

Comment: @Pimgd I will think about which answer I'll accept. It's hard for me because they are all good. Also, I just noticed that what I wrote about the `int[]` Array is false, right? I can just reallocate a new int with that size...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Reinventing the wheel

For the record, you can use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle collections. I suppose you're doing this for the sake of the exercise.

#### Ergonomy

The implementation is not ergonomic. It's not easy to use. I would expect from a generator to return something that's *iterable*, so that I can loop over its elements, and stop anytime I want, leaving the rest of the unexplored elements uncalculated. With generators you cannot walk backwards, so the `getPrevious` method wouldn't really make sense. Or perhaps generator is just not a good term for your purpose.

#### Excessive comments

There are too many pointless comments.

> ```
> /**
>  * Class constructor.
>  */
> public ShuffleGenerator(){
>
> // ...
>
> //if currentIndex is out of bounds, return -1 
> if( currentListIndex >= indexList.size() ){
> ```

Duh?

#### Good practices

Use the interface type in variable and method declaration, unless you have a specific need of the implementation. So instead of:

> ```
> private ArrayList<Integer> indexList;
> ```

Use:

```
private List<Integer> indexList;
```

Also, any member variable that can be final, make it final:

```
private final List<Integer> indexList;
```

#### Unit testing

Some unit tests would be nice, in case some of us might want to refactor your main logic and verify it's still correct. For example:

```
@Test
public void testGen_2_5() {
    ShuffleGenerator gen = new ShuffleGenerator();
    gen.initialize(2, 5);
    assertEquals(3, gen.getCurrent());
    assertEquals(1, gen.getNext());
    assertEquals(4, gen.getNext());
    assertEquals(0, gen.getNext());
    assertEquals(2, gen.getNext());
}
```

#### Suggested implementation

If you don't mind getting rid of `getCurrent` and `getPrevious`, then this would be a pure generator implementation that's simpler and more ergonomic:

```
class ShuffleGenerator {

    private final Random random;
    private final int size;

    ShuffleGenerator(int size, long seed) {
        this.random = new Random(seed);
        this.size = size;
    }

    Iterable<Integer> generate() {
        List<Integer> remaining = new ArrayList<>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            remaining.add(i);
        }

        return new Iterable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return !remaining.isEmpty();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Integer next() {
                        return remaining.remove(random.nextInt(remaining.size()));
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
public class ShuffleGeneratorTest {
    @Test
    public void testGen5() {
        ShuffleGenerator gen = new ShuffleGenerator(5, 0);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = gen.generate().iterator();
        assertEquals(0, (int) iter.next());
        assertEquals(4, (int) iter.next());
        assertEquals(2, (int) iter.next());
        assertEquals(3, (int) iter.next());
        assertEquals(1, (int) iter.next());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCannotIterateBeyond() {
        int size = 5;
        ShuffleGenerator gen = new ShuffleGenerator(size, 0);
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer item : gen.generate()) {
            assertNotNull(item);
            ++i;
        }
        assertEquals(size, i);
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testRemoveIter() {
        ShuffleGenerator gen = new ShuffleGenerator(5, 0);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = gen.generate().iterator();
        iter.remove();
    }

    @Test
    public void testReshuffle() {
        int size = 5;
        ShuffleGenerator gen = new ShuffleGenerator(size, 0);
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer item : gen.generate()) {
            assertNotNull(item);
            ++i;
        }
        assertEquals(size, i);
        i = 0;
        for (Integer item : gen.generate()) {
            assertNotNull(item);
            ++i;
        }
        assertEquals(size, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: As long as it's not `java.util.Iterator` because it implies you have remove semantics. And yes I'm aware that it's customary to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` but that breaks Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: I agree with the Class constructor comment being excessive, but not with "if currentIndex is out of bounds". Rephrasing might be a better idea - to "if currentIndex is out of bounds, return -1 - else ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException later". Not sure about this specific rewording though.

Comment: @Pimgd if your code needs commenting, you need to refactor it. Most of the comments are long and confused, because the code itself is confused.

Comment: @janos that's a dangerous philosophy. I think the occasional inline comment can be a huge boon. That said, you might be right here.

Comment: @Pimgd there are always exceptions. It's very rare that I feel the need to comment. And usually I'm in trouble when that happens.

Comment: Sadly, my work environment is not that clean... I wish it was, but it isn't. A comment will help in those cases.

Answer (score 8):

### Readability

```
currentListIndex-1 < 0
```

I'd make that

```
currentListIndex <= 0
```

That way you simplify the statement.

### Shuffling

[As pointed out in a previous answer on your first question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59316/49350), you can make use of [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)) [(example source if you're interested to see how it works)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Random%29). You can even keep using your Random object.

It would look kinda like this:

```
public void initialize( long seed, int size ){

    indexList.clear();
    currentListIndex = 0;

    if( size > 0 ){

        //fill it with indices
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
            indexList.add(i);
        }

        Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        Collections.shuffle(indexList, rnd);         
    }       
}
```

A further optimization would be to use [ArrayList.ensureCapacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)). This ensures that there will only be 1 resizing of the array, and could potentially speed up performance quite a bit if someone decided to, say... shuffle their entire song library.

### Comments

```
public int getCurrent()
```

is missing javadoc. I wouldn't document getters normally, but yours has special behavior if the index is out of bounds. That's why I would add javadoc so people know they might have to deal with `-1`.

### Further polishing

Label the arguments for your methods as `final`. You don't do anything with them, and with `final` you ensure this.

Additionally, the class name is a bit off. `ShuffleGenerator` sounds like it generates... shuffles... which is not really what it does. Maybe it's better off as a `ShuffledList` (but then you might have both the shuffled and the unshuffled indices)... or a `TrackShuffler` ... Ah! It's a `ShuffledPlaylist`!

A `ShuffledPlaylist` would be different from a normal Playlist in that it is, well, shuffled. And a normal Playlist, well, that's just a list of tracks with a counter indicating the current index. That's my reasoning for naming it a `ShuffledPlaylist`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest sticking to Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII). To that end I would rename the function

```
public void initialize( long seed, int size )
```

to

```
public void reshuffle( long seed, int size )
```

and make the constructor call `reshuffle`.

That way the user can't possibly create an object that is in an uninitialized state.